# gradle war plugin: make jar instead of classes for WEB-INF/lib?

Tags: gradle, war

gradle war plugin:

```
src/main/java/
         webapp/
```

Currently class files are put under WEB-INF/classes.

Is there an option to create jar from class files and put it under WEB-INF/lib?

The reason for this is that Proguard works for jars not classes.